# Assigned value or None,

Tags: python

I have a doubt, when I change the value of y23 to 23, instead of nothing appearing between the X and the E, I would like the value 0 to appear in the space of "y23".

```
numbers = ["y23", "e44", "x333", "l8888", "b5555", "a333"]

newlist = []

for x in numbers:
    if "x" in x:
        newlist.append(x)
for y in numbers:
    if "y" in y:
        newlist.append(y)
#if not y:

    #newlist.append(0)

for e in numbers:
    if "e" in e:
        newlist.append(e)

print(newlist)
```

Resultado
['x333', 'y23', 'e44']

But if I change y23 to 23 I want the result to be ['x333', '0', 'e44'] and not ['x333', 'e44']

tks

Comment: if there is no letter in an entry, do you want to append '0'?

Answer (score 1):

Build the three lists, and before you combine them replace empty lists with ["0"]:

```
>>> numbers = ["y23", "e44", "x333", "l8888", "b5555", "a333"]
>>> sum(([i for i in numbers if c in i] or ["0"] for c in ("x", "y", "e")), start=[])
['x333', 'y23', 'e44']
>>> numbers[0] = "23"
>>> sum(([i for i in numbers if c in i] or ["0"] for c in ("x", "y", "e")), start=[])
['x333', '0', 'e44']
```

Comment: these variables are part of a gcode 3d printer, the idea is to order the letters and where they have no value insert a zero . Thanks for your help